# How to deploy asp.net core (backend) and angular 8 (frontend) appplications together to Google App Engine?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to move my project from a shared hosting to the Google Cloud Platform.

My application consists of a backend (asp.net core) and a frontend (angular 8). They communicate only by web api calls. In my local environment and on my current host (shared windows hosting) it's running perfectly. I only need to publish my web project via web deploy from Visual Studio and it deploys the .net and the angular app together with this one click.

Portion of my Startup.cs:

```
if (!Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "MyAngularApp/dist";
    });
}
```

Among other possible solutions I found the **App Engine** that I want to deploy my application to. I created the app.yaml files for my backend and for my frontend too.

One by one I can deploy them (backend for the 'default' service/frontend to the 'api' service), so they will be deployed to a separate domain.

My solution doesn't work, I guess my approach is wrong. Should these two apps be configured in one yaml file? I'm looking for the best practice how it should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be solved by one app.yaml without containerization:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 5
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6
  target_concurrent_requests: 10

resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: AngularApp/dist/index.html
  upload: AngularApp/dist/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: AngularApp/dist
```

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario in particular, since there are dependencies between aspnet.core and angular, the smoothest migration to  Google App Engine would be to containerize your applications and use App Engine Flex with [custom](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes) runtime.

This would solve the common issue of "It works on development but not on production". Otherwise you could have some errors while deploying to other App Engine products like Standard or Flex because their runtime may not include all the dependencies your project has.

In a summary, you need to:

1. Create a Dockerfile that containerizes your aspdotnet/angular application. I have found [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-aspnetcore/#0) good example of how to containerize a dotnet application. Following the latter may be not be enough since it does not contain all the docker statements, but you can also use [this](https://dev.to/marwan01/deploy-an-angular-app-using-google-cloud-run-3p4a) other one to help you fill the missing docker statements for angular.
2. Create an `app.yaml` file with the following configuration.
   `runtime: custom`
   `env: flex`
   `service: [SERVICE_NAME]`
3. Run `gcloud app deploy`

As you can see the most elaborate part of the list above is docker but it has a lot of perks to have your application in a container since deploying with Google App Engine flex custom runtime is minimal.